# Joomla timezone mismatch

Tags: joomla, php, mysql, timezone

For some reason Civi is using UTC and not the Joomla time. The system, and php and mysql times are reporting correctly (Brisbane)
. 
For Mysql I have run the following to get its time;

SELECT NOW() AS 'NOW';

For PHP I ran this

echo 'PHP date: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Both report correct time.
I also set the time zone in a local php.ini file and php is picking this up and reporting this correctly.

The error that Civi displays shows PHP as having the wrong time.

I see a timezone table in the database which is empty. Can I hardcode it in there? What else might be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out joomla on the cpanel install in question linux reads the php.ini file from the /administrator directory not site root. I had put one in the root dierctory and had checked if php was reporting it correctly and it was. So now fixed.